# C# Application waiting until Thread is complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application where a thread is used to calculate a bunch of numbers but the problem is that the application finishes before the Thread completes the calculation and returns the calculated number. What's the way of making the application wait until the calculation is done?

Here's my code:

```
namespace ThreadWaiting
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int number=0;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Calculate);
            t.Start();

            //Wait here until processed?

            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Calculate(object obj)
        {
            number = 2 + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that, you will see that it prints "0" and not "4".

Any ideas guys? Thanks!

Comment: Thread synchronization FTW!

Comment: [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) is all you need

Answer (score 2):

To wait until a thread is done, you `Join` it:

```
t.Join();
```

Comment: I should add this below the t.Start() ?

Comment: If you want to wait for the thread at this point, then yes. Starting a thread just to wait for it doesn't make a lot of sense though.

Comment: Hmmm then what's the best way to Process an output in a thread and retrieve it?

Comment: Why do you want a thread? The whole point of a thread is that you can do stuff while it's running.

Comment: To make things efficient and faster. My Thread handles a method that does a lot of heavy calculations in my original Project. But the Calculations need to be returned to the main UI and thus this problem. But the Join solved it. Is there a better way sir?

Comment: If you Join on another thread in your UI, you will be back to step one because you will have blocked your GUI. But if you solved your problem, then everything is fine.